# Find the sum of the following infinite series. Don't know how to separate the denominators out.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the following infinite series:
$$\frac{1}{6}+\frac{13}{6^2}+\frac{19}{6^3}+\frac{97}{6^4}+\cdots+\frac{3^n+(-2)^n}{6^n}+\cdots$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{3^n+(-2)^n}{6^n} = \left(\dfrac{3}{6}\right)^n + \left(\dfrac{-2}{6}\right)^n= \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^n+\left(\dfrac{-1}{3}\right)^n$. Are you able to take it from here?

Comment: $(\frac{1}{2})^n$ = 1 but not sure how to calculate the summation of the other one?

Comment: @SamuelWong: it is a geometric progression. Do you know how to find the sum of an infinite geometric progression? ([hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum))

Comment: Hint: $r+r^2+\cdots = \dfrac{r}{1-r}$. Apply this formula for $r = -\dfrac{1}{3}$.

Comment: For future reference (such as a series like this appearing on an exam), this separation into two (or more) separate geometric series only works if _every one_ of the individual series gives a finite sum ("converges"); that is to say, all of the series must have ratios with $ \ -1 \ < \ r \ < \ 1 \ $ .

Comment: Thanks for the hint (and I was so dumb. I blame it for a brain freeze.) And thanks for the future reference.